# How to change Installation Folder Url after publish the Application

Tags: c#, deployment, installation, clickonce, publish

How can I change the Installation Folder Url and Update location of a **C# click once application** after publish the application using MSBuild.exe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atlast i figured it myself.

Here is how :

Create a batch file by copying the following commands and replace

[PATH] -> Absolute path to mage.exe

[path to current version]-> published folder having the current version

[deploy path]-> published folder path having the exe file

[New Installation Url]-> Installation url you want to update

"[PATH]\mage.exe" -Update "[path to current version]\MyApp.application" -ProviderUrl "[New Installation Url]/MyApp.application"

"[PATH]\mage.exe" -Update "[path to current version]\MyApp.application" -AppManifest "[path to current version]\MyApp.exe.manifest"

"[PATH]\mage.exe" -Sign "[path to current version]\MyApp.application" -CertFile "[path]\TemporaryKey.pfx" -Password mypassword

"[PATH]\mage.exe" -Update [deploy path]\MyApp.application" -ProviderUrl "[New Installation Url]/MyApp.application"

"[PATH]\mage.exe" -Update "[deploy path]\MyApp.application" -AppManifest "[path to current version]\MyApp.exe.manifest"

"[PATH]\mage.exe" -Sign "[deploy path]\MyApp.application" -CertFile "[path]\TemporaryKey.pfx" -Password mypassword

"[deploy path]\setup.exe" /url="[New Installation Url]/"

Comment: i have no .application in my "Application Files" folder. The only .application file is in the root where setup.exe is, while manifest file is in the Application Files folder. What exactly do I need to update/sign im my case? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @no9 hi, in your Application file folder there is a ClickOnce Application Deployment Manifest (Check its property its a .application file)[path to current version]\MyApp.application means [path to current version]\ClickOnce Application Deployment Manifest file, let me inform if u hav any issues.

Comment: .Application file is the ClickOnce Application Deployment Manifest  file :)

Comment: I am still unable to figure out what actions to execute in my case. Yes I am using the clickOnce deployment and I want to automate it because I want to do this outside visual studio. The problem is that I always have to create 2x publish (once for test and once for production). The difference is "Installation folder URL", because my application is checking for updates there. So I did 2x msbuild on two locations and now I need to update the "Installation folder URL" in the manifest and setup for both... Can you please elaborate what actions i need to take to make it work?

Comment: My structure is like this: On root of deployment there is "Application Files" (has a subfolder "myApp.version" that holds "resources folder", bunch of ".dll" files and a ".exe", ".config" and ".exe.manifest" files). Besides that on the root is only ".application" file and "setup.exe" file.

Comment: From your comments i understood that their is no  ClickOnce Application Deployment Manifest  file in the myApp_1_0_0_0(version) folder,am i correct?

Comment: there is only MyApp.manifest file ... and no MyApp.application file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47393/discussion-between-sumeshk-and-no9)